# What does the "w" mean after a shared library name?

Tags: linux, shared-library

Some of my libraries have a "w" after the name. What does this signify?

For example I have the following shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib`:

```
libncurses.so
libncursesw.so
libmenu.so
libmenuw.so
libform.so
libformw.so
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “w” stands for “wide characters”, *i.e.* characters which occupy potentially more than one byte in memory; quoting [the FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html):

> I chose to implement the wide-character support using a different library name, "ncursesw". Doing that allowed me to maintain compatibility with applications that used the existing "ncurses" library.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character), for those that want more information regarding wide characters.